# Accept function in argument with empty interface return type

Tags: go

I would like to understand why the code snippet below does not compile. What is the Go way of accepting a function as a function argument that may have any return type?

```
package main

func main() {
    test(a) // Error: cannot use a (type func() string) as type func() interface {} in argument to test
    test(b) // Error: cannot use b (type func() int) as type func() interface {} in argument to test
}

func a() string {
    return "hello"
}

func b() int {
    return 1
}

func test(x func() interface{}) {

    // some code...
    v := x()
    // some more code....
}
```

Play: https://play.golang.org/p/CqbuEZGy12

**My solution based on Volker's answer:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    // Wrap function a and b with an anonymous function
    // that has an empty interface return type. With this
    // anonymous function, the call signature of test
    // can be satisfied without needing to modify the return
    // type of function a and b.

    test(func() interface{} {
        return a()
    })

    test(func() interface{} {
        return b()
    })
}

func a() string {
     return "hello"
}

func b() int {
    return 1
}

func test(x func() interface{}) {
    v := x()
    fmt.Println(v)  
}
```

Play: https://play.golang.org/p/waOGBZZwN7

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You tripped over a very common misconception for Go newcomers: The empty interface `interface{}` does *not* mean "any type". Really, it does not. Go is statically typed. The empty interface `interface {}` is an actual (strongly typed type) like e.g. `string` or `struct{Foo int}` or `interface{Explode() bool}`.

That means if something has the type `interface{}` it has that type and not "any type".

Your function

```
func test(x func() interface{})
```

takes one parameter. This parameter is a (parameterless function) which returns a specific type, the type `interface{}`. You can pass any function to `test` which matches this signature: "No parameters and return `interface{}`". None of your functions `a` and `b` match this signature.

As said above: `interface {}` is not a magical abbreviation for "whatever",it is a distinct static type.

You have to change e.g. a to:

```
func a() interface{} {
    return "hello"
}
```

Now this might look strange as you return a `string` which is not of type `interface{}`.  This works because any type is assignable to variables of type `interface{}` (as every type has at least no methods :-).

Comment: I agree with your solution more :) . If it is possible, it is better to avoid reflection.

Comment: This is like the difference between pressing any key and pressing the "any" key.

Answer (score 3):

As the [Go specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) states:

> A function type denotes the set of all functions with the same parameter and *result types*

In your case, your *result types* differ (`string` vs `interface{}`)

To be able to receive a function with any kind of result type, `test` would have to be defined as:

```
func text(x interface{}) { ... }
```

and then you will have to use [reflect package](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) to call the function stored in `x`.

**Edit**

Such a `test` function would look like this:

```
func test(x interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)

    if v.Kind() != reflect.Func {
        panic("Test requires a function")
    }

    t := v.Type()

    if t.NumIn() != 0 && t.NumOut() != 1 {
        panic("Function type must have no input parameters and a single return value")
    }

    values := v.Call(nil)

    val := values[0].Interface()
    // some more code..
}
```

**Playground:** https://play.golang.org/p/trC2lOSLNE